# How do I add parameters to an object using variables?

Tags: javascript

I have this snippet of code:

```
var ShopLogicOptions = {};
ShopLogicOptions.params = {orderId: "'" + JS_OrderNo + "'", cartItems:[JS_arrCartItems], subTotal: "'" + JS_SubTotal + "'",...
```

How do I correctly put variable JS_OrderNo in the position it is at?

The other server is receiving this: "'9134832'",

And it should be this: '9134832',

EDIT: When I document.write JS_OrderNO it looks like this 9134832, so I have to add the single quotes.

Comment: You *don't* have to add the single quotes.  It looks like that because it's a number.  Heck, `document.write('abc')`, you don't see quotes there either.  The quotes are only needed when making string literals.  `"'" + JS_OrderNo + "'"`.  This literally makes the string `'9134832'` (the quotes are *part* of the string).  You don't need to add quotes.

Comment: I didn't understand your edit at all! why do you need to quote?

Comment: I am sorry if I wasn't clear. The reason is because that is how shop logic wants them, all variables can be treated as strings. This is just a tracking app.

Comment: @JoJo: All variables can be treated as strings without any processing by you.  Just assume it's a string, and it should just work.

Comment: @Rocket. But if a function expect to get strings ONLY, (for some unknown reason) numbers won't do. you can simply parse any variable to string using `""+ variable` or `String(variable)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotes.

```
var ShopLogicOptions = {};
ShopLogicOptions.params = {
    orderId: JS_OrderNo,
    cartItems: [JS_arrCartItems],
    subTotal: JS_SubTotal,
    ...
};
```

If you really need a string instead of a number, use this:

```
orderId: String(JS_OrderNo),
```

Comment: Maybe this is what he **should** have asked, but he's asking for a string.

Comment: Thanks, Are the single apostrophes automatically added then?

Comment: He didn't mention that he needs a string. My guess is that he simply doesn't want quotes in the value. @JoJo: Try it without converting to a string. Only if that doesn't work change the code to create a string. Then the value would be enclosed in quotation marks when converting it to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

remove the single quote

```
{orderId: "" + JS_OrderNo
```